# Visual Studio Team Services (VSO) Jasmine testcase code coverage

Tags: azure-devops, karma-jasmine, azure-pipelines

We are using jasmine testing framework which is executing via karma test runner. Everything works fine in my local, But in Team Services (previously VSO), while we try to execute the test cases, all test cases executed successfully but code coverage is empty even after enabling by throwing following error

```
    PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 139 of 139 SUCCESS (1.389 secs / 1.41 secs)
    TOTAL: 139 SUCCESS
     Finished 'test' after 1.05 min
    C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd install istanbul
    npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
    npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
    npm WARN paalar@1.0.0 No description
    npm WARN paalar@1.0.0 No repository field.
    C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe ./node_modules/istanbul/lib/cli.js cover --report cobertura --report html -i .\src\*.ts ./node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH=node_modules/jasmine/lib/examples/jasmine.json **/*specs.ts
    Started
    No specs found
    Finished in 0.001 seconds
    No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information
    Starting 'Publish-CodeCoverage' cmdlet...
    Fetched BuildId '656'.
    System.ArgumentException: File 'C:\a\1\s\coverage\cobertura-coverage.xml' does not exist or is not accessible.
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.CodeCoverage.SummaryReader.ReadSummaryFile(String summaryXmlLocation)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.CodeCoverage.CoberturaSummaryReader.GetCodeCoverageSummary(String summaryXmlLocation)
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.CodeCoverage.PublishCodeCoverageCmd.TryGenerateAndPublishCodeCoverageSummary()
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.CodeCoverage.PublishCodeCoverageCmd.ProcessRecord()
```

Build definition for code coverage

[image]

Comment: Does it have code coverage result if you run gulp command to collect code coverage?

Comment: @starain no code coverage is empty. Did I missed any thing?

Comment: What're detail steps to test code coverage?

Comment: Based on the error message, no specs found, what's the structure of your project and what's the detail code of guilfile.js?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message: no specs found.

You specified **/*specs.ts, first, you need to check whether it is correct, secondly, you can check Working Directory in Advanced section.

[image]